# Difference between flex unset and flex none with IE 11

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

What is the difference between `flex: unset` and `flex: none`?  I haven't been able to find any specific documentation that tells what `flex: unset` actually does.  Also, `flex: unset` does not seem to work in IE 11.

For some contenxt, we recently ran into an issue on IE 11 where we had some class `.cta-button` that had `flex: 1 0 auto` and when we add the class `.flex-unset` it sets `flex: unset` and overrides the `flex: 1 0 auto`.  That works for Chrome, Firefox, and Edge but no IE 11.  For IE 11, we had to set `flex: none` rather than `flex: unset`.

Comment: In short: IE doesn't support unset in any case. see https://caniuse.com/#search=unset

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset unset not supported by IE, just use none

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I can't believe I didn't check `caniuse`. I was just going off of google and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex but never got to the specific unset page.

Comment: In case of browsers that support both, `unset` resets to the inherited value or if no value inherited the default value  (`0 1 auto`) none sets the values to the none value (`0 0 auto`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to understanding the difference is by understanding what unset actually does in general.

unset is just a hybrid of using inherit and initial.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset

As you can see if you scroll down on that page, IE does not support unset. If you know a flex attribute is not being inherited on your class, you can just set flex to initial.